# MySQL Select where rows are not in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - `forum_topics` and `topics_posts`. I want to select rows from `forum_topics` which have no posts in the `topics_posts` table, but cannot figure out how to. Does an SQL statement like this exist:

```
select from * `forum_topics` where have no rows in `topics_posts`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like that:

```
select * from forum_topics t
where not exists (
    select * from topics_posts p
    where p.topic_id = t.id
);
```

Although using an outer join, might be a bit faster than the subquery:

```
select * from forum_topics t left outer join forum_posts p
on t.id = p.topic_id
where p.id is null;
```